# What does .then(console.log) mean?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I've come across the following fetch and didn't understand how it works

```
fetch("https://api.github.com").then(res => res.json()).then(console.log)
```

It prints the result after converting it to `json`.

I usually do it like the following

```
fetch("https://api.github.com").then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Could you explain how the `console.log` accesses the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` is a function. So is `res => console.log(res)`. The latter is a simple arrow function that accepts and uses exactly one argument, where `console.log`, the original function can accept multiple arguments.

When a single argument is provided, the two are equivalent, `res => console.log(res)` is just adding an unnecessary layer of wrapping. If you have a top-level function (not a method, JS is bad at the concept of bound methods), that already does what you need, there's no need to wrap it an extra layer of arrow function wrapping.

You told `.then` to call `console.log` when the result was available by passing `console.log` to it, so it effectively did the equivalent of:

```
stored_func = console.log;
// ... wait for Promise to resolve ...
stored_func(result_of_promise);
```

where your arrow function changes just the first line:

```
stored_func = (res => console.log(res));
// ... wait for Promise to resolve ...
stored_func(result_of_promise);
```